# How to retrive information from a json substring in a json column in sql query

Tags: sql, json, qsqlquery

I have a table that looks like this:

`[type] [localid] [data] [executed by]`

in the data column there is json

```
{
   "type":"music",
   "local_id":"00000086",
   "recording":{
      "album":null,
      "title":"null",
      "local_id":"OUHA_A46013SG0001",
      "composers":[
         "null"
      ],
      "label_name":"null",
      "main_artist":"null",
      "production_country":null
   },
   "starts_at":null,
   "parallel_hash":"8fe1dfd71f8c19be83806455d5194532",
   "report_id":"6bd9e074-5f38-402f-a706-7916def5a9e1",
   "duration_in_seconds":120.4
}
```

i am able to retrive all information into a column for every information except i cannot seperate the information in the recording {}.
I have used select data::json->>'type' as type, and so on... and have got the info

`[type][localid][recording][starts_at][report_id][duration_in_seconds]`

but i also want the information seperated in the recording data. so that the result is

`[type][local_id][recording_album][recording_title][recording_local_id][recording_composers][recording_label_name][recording_main_artist][recording_production_country][starts_at][parallel_hash][report_id][duration_in_seconds]`

Can anyone show me how?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Could you list the sql query?

Comment: I am asking for this information through metabase.
i have tried //
select data::json->>'type' as type,
data::json->>'playtime_report_id' as id, 
data::json->>'duration_in_seconds' as secs,
data::json->>'recording' as rec_data
from events "ev1" where name = 'playback_created'
//

Comment: but when asking for data::json->>'album'  it gives no info.

Comment: Can't you align queries and use rec_data to recover album information?

Comment: How? by joining and using a new select? i don't think i understand.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out using this....
data::json->'recording'->>'album' as album,
data::json->'recording'->>'title' as title,

and so on